# Stop deletion of admin where name like 'string_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to stop A particular Admin from being removed from the database with ruby on rails
I have tried a few things but heres the code as it stands

Edit 2 changed User.name to @user.name

Model

```
after_destroy :can_not_destroy_super_admin

private
def can_not_destroy_super_admin
    if @user.name == "super admin"
        raise "Can't delete this admin"
    end
end
```

I think its a problem with User.name, but I know its seeing this code because I've had errors raising issues with different code I've tried in here.

I'm aware that this is a relatively crude method for stopping deletion of an admin but it's a simple way of getting what I need done.

Any suggestions or help is very much appreciated.

Edit.1

Here is the destroy method

Controller

```
def destroy
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 begin
  @user.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.name} deleted"
 rescue Exception => e
  flash[:notice] = e.message
 end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

Comment: Ehm, you have `after_destroy` callback. See, "after"? It's too late, the user's gone already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your destroy action looks something like this?

```
def destroy
  @user = user.find params[:id]
  @user.destroy
end
```

If this is the case, the user you want to check against in your callback is `@user.name`, not `User.name`. You want to ensure that the actual user instance you called destroy on is the same one you're checking the name of.

**Edit**: As determined in the comments, the callback is actually on the model, I misinterpreted as being in the controller. In the model, to reference the objects name, only `name` is needed, not `User.name` or `@user.name`.

Comment: I have tried changing the `User.name` to `@user.name` in the `can_not_destroy_super_admin` but that throws an error

Comment: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: i've updated the `can_not_destroy_super_admin` to how it looks now.
at this point its giving me the error above

Comment: waitasec.... where is this callback code, in your model? If so, then you don't need to use `@user` at all, just `name`.